# What's different about this ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I was trying to substitute either a comma or a percent sign, and it continually failed, so I opened up IRB and tried some things out. Can anyone explain to me why the first regex (IRB line 13) doesn't work but the flipped version does (IRB line 15)? I've looked it up and down and I don't see any typos, so it must be something to do with the rule but I can't see what.

```
b.gsub(/[%]*|[,]*/,"")
# => "245,324" 
b.gsub(/[,]*/,"")
# => "245324" 
b.gsub(/[,]*|[%]*/,"")
# => "245324" 
b
# => "245,324"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ruby happily finds `[%]*` zero times throughout your string and does the substitution.  Check out this result:

```
b = '232,000'
puts b.gsub(/[%]*/,"-")

--output:--
-2-3-2-,-0-0-0-
```

If you put all the characters that you want to erase into the same character class, then you will get the result you want:

```
b = "%245,324,000%"
puts b.gsub(/[%,]*/, '')
--output:--

245324000
```

Even then, there are a lot of needless substitutions going on:

```
b = "%245,324,000%"
puts b.gsub(/[%,]*/, '-')

--output:--
--2-4-5--3-2-4--0-0-0--
```

It's the `zero or more` that gets you into trouble because ruby can find lots of places where there are 0 percent signs or 0 commas.  You actually don't want to do substitutions where ruby finds zero of your characters, instead you want to do substitutions where at least one of your characters occurs:

```
b = '%232,000,000%'
puts b.gsub(/%+|,+/,"")

--output:--
232000000
```

Or, equivalently:

```
puts b.gsub(/[%,]+/, '')
```

Also, note that regexes are like double quoted strings, so you can interpolate into them--it's as if the delimiters `//` are double quotes:

```
one_or_more_percents = '%+'
one_or_more_commas = ',+'
b = '%232,000,000%'

puts b.gsub(/#{one_or_more_percents}|#{one_or_more_commas}/,"")

--output:--
232000000
```

But when your regexes consist of single characters, just use a character class: `[%,]+`

Comment: ahh, as in | (alternative) which i guess means "do this, or do that" but what I really want is "do this, AND do that", thanks!

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer, Put all the characters that you want to remove in the same character class for AND.  See my edit.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer, Go here: http://rubular.com and paste in the regex `[%]*|[,]*`, and for your string put in: 245,324, and look at the results.